# Redshift - select query table name is in double quotes does not work

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-spark-sql, integration-testing, amazon-redshift

I am writing unit tests where I am using in-memory H2 DB to test the logic. The actual code runs on redshift since redshift uses psql JDBC driver I chose H2 as a workaround.

But my redshift table name contains dot (".") operator in it.
example :

```
select * from emp.vikas;
```

In the unit test, the query fails saying "schema 'emp' not found".
For a workaround, I have added double quotes to the table name in the query.

But now redshift query fails while running the actual code. (Not unit test)
saying "relation "emp.vikas" does not exist"

My question is, how can we have a running test case for redshift queries?

Comment: single quotes work in some cases, not sure about your case

Comment: No. Single quotes also fails on redshift.

Answer (score 2):

In Redshift you use `"` to quote relation names (tables/views etc) - this is useful if your relation contains special characters (like `.`) or collides with keywords (`group`, `table`).

Also in Redshift you can reference a relation by using `schema.relation_name` notation or `database.schema.relation_name`. You can also user just `relation_name` if your relations reside in `public` schema or when you have to set the [search path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Schemas_and_tables.html#c_Search_path) properly so that Redshift knows what you refer to.

For example, if your Redshift database is `my_db`, and schema is `my_schema` and table `my_table` fou can refer to it like this:

- `my_db.my_schema.my_table` or
- `my_schema.my_table` or
- `"my_db"."my_schema"."my_table"` or
- `"my_schema"."my_table"`

if your table name is `my.table` the you *have to* quote it:

- `my_db.my_schema."my.table"` or
- `my_schema."my.table"` or
- `"my_db"."my_schema"."my.table"` or
- `"my_schema"."my.table"`

if you use `public` schema and your table name is `emp.vikas` then you refer to it:

- `my_db.public."emp.vikas"` or
- `public."emp.vikas"` or
- `"emp.vikas"`

If your schema name is `emp` and your table name is `vikas` and you use `my_db` database then you can refer to your table as:

- `my_db.emp.vikas` or
- `emp.vikas` or
- `"my_db"."emp"."vikas"` or
- `"emp"."vikas"`

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks botchniaque, but `select * from "emp.vikas"` does not work in redshift. Also, I am running spark java code using api call `sparkSession.sqlContext().read` to read data from redshift. There I am not able to set search_path (command used : `set search_path = emp`) because search_path works for a particular session.

Comment: If your schema is `emp` and your table `vikas` then you should reference is as `"emp"."vikas"` - I just modified the last example to show that.

Answer (score 0):

> how can we have a running test case for redshift queries?

you have at least the following options:

1. run your tests on redshift. no other product will give you the same API. it's a bit more complex to set up such an environment, maybe it will cost some money but that's the only way to get really reliable tests
2. find a product developed to simulate redshift. some products have local versions. like local DynamoDB, [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto), [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack). level of confidence will vary with this solution but it may be enough for a lot of use cases
3. make your code smart enough to adjust to different storages. if you know that API/query difference is trivial, don't hardcode your queries but use some kind of query builder/translator that detects the storage and convert the query using proper dialect (like adding quotes). this part of code won't be tested on your production storage but maybe it's small enough and changes so rarely it's not worth to spend money on proper real-storage tests
4. don't test it. maybe that code will never ever change, maybe manual tests done once will be enough and cheapest, maybe it's enough to test if all your query strings contain quotes, maybe this specific part of that specific app is not critical enough to invest so much time on writing those pretty expensive tests
5. use some mix of all the above methods